# How to increase x-pointer size

Tags: exwm, mouse-pointer

I would like to increase the size of the x-pointer (mouse cursor) in Emacs on plain Xorg (I'm running Emacs 28.2 and EXWM as window manager). The standard X solutions work but don't seem to influence the emacs frame and since I have a HDPI display the x-pointer is nearly invisible.

In Emacs I tried to set the `x-pointer-shape` as well as the mouse face attributes but size is not influenced by the height/width attributes.

I'm sure there must be a way to influence the size of the pointer but don't find a hint in either the documentation or searching the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me (on guile system Linux).  I installed the package `xcursor-themes` and set size and theme in `.Xresources` to

```
Xcursor*theme: whiteglass
Xcursor*size: 32
```

With this standard Xcursor theme the selection is not ignored by emacs (as in all my previous trials) and I can now freely scale my `x-pointer`, up to a maximum size of 48.

The X-Server needs to be restarted. `xrdb -merge .Xresources' has no effect.

PS: interestingly I found this solution with the assistance of ChatGPT